# How to use camera QR Code Reader on MAUI Blazor Hybrid

Tags: qr-code, maui, maui-blazor

Has anyone found a working solution on scanning QR Codes from a Blazor MAUI Hybrid App?

I have found number of libraries (e.g. BigIslandBarcoding, ZXing.Net) for "normal" Blazor but nothing speicifc to do this on a mobile device (iOS and Android) from razor page (in BlazorWebView).

I'm looking for a simple action to open the camera reader/scanner on button click but can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

I played with this today because I am porting my Blazor server app to MAUI Blazor and had a same problem.

Edit:
**You dont need this part bellow**

*I managed to fix it by using this project
https://github.com/MackinnonBuck/MauiBlazorPermissionsExample
To get device specific permissions and then I installed*

**Edit: This library has a problem when you try to publish as Release**

*https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile*

so use this one instead

https://github.com/g0dpain/ZXing.Net.Mobile

It is made for Xamarin but it works in MAUI just fine. What you need to do is add this code in Android project MainActivity.cs file

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}



protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(Application);

    ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);

}
```

And in your Razor page you can call it like this

```
async Task ScanBarcode()
{

    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
   
    var result = await scanner.Scan();

    barcode = result.Text;


}
```

I tried it in Android emulator and on real device and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [the project](https://github.com/datvm/JsPermissionHandler) linked in the [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72999249/653457) I have been making many projects that use `getUserMedia`. I have made a Nuget package for it on [Github](https://github.com/datvm/JsPermissionHandler) and [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsPermissionHandler) so you can use reuse them in your projects:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new BlazorWebViewHandler()            
        // Add whichever you need:
        .AddCamera()
        .AddMicrophone()
        .AddGeolocation()
        // blazorWebView is the name of your BlazorWebView
        .AddInitializingHandler(blazorWebView);
}
```

On Android and iOS, you need to add relevant permission entries in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Info.plist`.